# labeled statement - incorrect definition?

Tags: javascript, labeled-statements

For JavaScript's `label` syntax, [JS MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/statements/label#Syntax):

> `label` :
>      `statement`
>
> `label`: Any JavaScript identifier that is not a reserved word.
>
> `statement`: A JavaScript statement.
>
> `break` can be used with **any** labeled statement, and `continue` can be used with looping labeled statements.

According to that, you can break as follows:

```js
statement: {
  console.log("this will log");
  break statement;
  console.log("this will not log");
}
```

And, since it says that you can break **any** labeled statements, I would've expected this to work:

```js
function func() {
  console.log("works?")
  break statement;
  console.log("this too?")

}

statement: {
  console.log("this will log");
  func();
  console.log("this will not log");
}
// throws Uncaught SyntaxError: Undefined label 'statement'
```

But it throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Undefined label 'statement'`

I thought maybe I can update the `func` as follows:

```js
function func(breakMe) {
  console.log("works?")
  break breakMe;
  console.log("this too?")

}

statement: {
  console.log("this will log");
  func(statement);
  console.log("this will not log");
}

// throwsUncaught SyntaxError: Undefined label 'statement'
```

But `statement` cannot be referenced that way (throwing `statement is not defined`);

Same error here:

```js
    statement: {
      function func() {
        console.log("works?")
        break statement;
        console.log("this too?")
      }
      console.log("this will log");
      func();
      console.log("this will not log");
    }
```

It seems I have a fundamental misunderstanding as to what exactly is this "any" referring to.

Given that this works:

```js
labelOne: {
  console.log("this will log")
  labelTwo: {
    console.log("will log too");
    break labelOne;
    console.log("this won't log");
  }
  console.log("neither will this");
}
```

maybe a more accurate description would be:

> `break` can only be used with labeled statement in the context of those statements.

But even so, with this description, `func()` should've broken the execution of the statement labeled `statement`, since it was in the same context from my POV.

So is the syntax incorrectly/incompletely defined or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `break` must be literally nested inside the `label`. It's perfectly possible to call `func` from outside a labelled context, so `break` wouldn't refer to anything. The same goes for `break` and `continue` in reference to loops, they must be *literally* within the loop statement.

Put another way, a function must be a self-contained executable snippet. You must be able to look at a function and be able to tell what it does. `break` in that function doesn't obviously belong to any loop or label, it's nonsensical there. That meaning can't just be available at call-time, it must be available at time of declaration.

Comment: When you say *so `break` wouldn't refer to anything* you actually mean **but** `break` wouldn't refer to anything?

Comment: ?! "But" vs. "so"? I do mean "so", as in "in this case".

Comment: How did you reach the conclusion that *The `break` must be literally nested inside the label*? Is there any official info on this?

Comment: *"The break statement needs to be nested within the referenced label."* – https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break